# Неотложка и машина скорой помощи - это разные понятия?

Tags: лексика

Неотложка и машина скорой помощи - это разные понятия?

В Словаре Ожегова есть такое определение:

НЕОТЛО́ЖКА, -и, жен. (разг.).
1. То же, что неотложная медицинская помощь (медицинское учреждение или его отдел). Позвонить в неотложку. При поликлинике есть н.
2. Автомашина этого учреждения, приезжающая с врачом для оказания неотложной помощи. Вызвать неотложку. Приехала неотложка.

https://www.msk.kp.ru/daily/26646/3665506/:

Неотложка приезжает на такие вызовы, где нет угрозы жизни, но есть угроза здоровью пациента.

«Скорая помощь» приезжает в экстренных случаях, при угрозе жизни и здоровью.

Можно ли в публицистике их считать синонимами?

Answer (score 3):

Если появляется машина такого вида, на неё ссылаются как на "**скорую (помощь)**" (*машину* скорой помощи) и "**карету скорой помощи**" (под старину - у журналистов; не существует "кареты неотложной помощи"). Под неотложкой обычно понимают специализированную **службу**, которая приезжает на такой же машине. Эту машину *по внешним признакам* (возможны даже соответствующие надписи на ней) распознавать не принято; конкретизация назначения такой машины обычно основана на *знании*: кем "укомплектовано" транспортное средство. Если вызывают *неотложку*, то предполагается, что приедет не просто дежурный врач для оказания первой помощи или быстрой госпитализации, а специалист нужного профиля, ждут его, а не машину. Поэтому в контексте физически наблюдаемой машины "скорая" и "неотложка" - не синонимы (*машина* и *служба*).

Comment: Вы ошибаетесь, неотложная помощь в городах России выезжает на менее важные случаи, в ней приезжает именно дежурный врач.

Answer (score 2):

Это вопрос относится не к сфере лингвистики, а к организации системы медицинского обслуживания в конкретном регионе. В крупных городах России действует двойная система: скорой и неотложной помощи. Кратко: *скорая помощь* - это особая городская служба, *неотложная* - это служба районных поликлиник. Подробно можно прочитать в АИФ https://aif.ru/dontknows/1236504 или МК https://www.msk.kp.ru/daily/26646/3665506/

В регионах, особенно крупных и малонаселенных, возможности централизации нет (машина не в состоянии быстро добраться из центра в район), поэтому и скорая, и неотложная помощь объединены в единую местную службу.

Comment: Поддерживаю ответ "в целом", хотя не совсем понимаю, как Вы ограничиваете сферу лингвистики. Скажем, профессиональные и другие жаргоны, диалекты, языковые особенности крупных городов или даже отдельных кварталов в них — разве всё это (и многое т.п.) не входит в сферу лингвистики?

Comment: Я имел в виду вот что: синонимичность, о которой спрашивается в вопросе, в данном случае определяется не языковыми нормами, но нормативными актами. В малых городах, где скорая и неотложная помощь осуществляется одной службой, это полные синонимы. Если завтра службы разделят, то нельзя уже будет говорить о синонимичности, и это не вопрос изменений в языке.